# Getting nothing when define routes in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am new to Angular2. I am trying to create routes as given [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).
I created three components like `HeaderComponent`, `SidebarComponent` and `UiElementsComponents`. All of these are declared in main.module file (root module). Everything works great till now. But when I define routes it stops from displaying anything. Even doesn't display any error. Here is my code.

main.module.ts

```
//Main (root) module of App is defined here.
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule }        from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MainComponent }        from './../components/main.component';
import { HeaderComponent }      from './../components/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent }     from './../components/sidebar.component';
import { UiElementsComponent }  from './../components/ui-elements.component';


    const routes: Routes = [
                            { path: '', redirectTo: '/test', pathMatch: 'full' },
                            { path: 'test', component: UiElementsComponent},
                        ];
    // The root module of the pratham app.
    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ 
                        BrowserModule,
                        RouterModule.forRoot(routes) 
                    ],
      declarations: [ 
                        MainComponent, 
                        HeaderComponent,
                        SidebarComponent,
                        UiElementsComponent
                    ],
      bootstrap:    [ MainComponent ]
    })

    export class MainModule { }
```

main.component.ts

```
//Main (root) component of Pratham is defined here.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector:   'prtm-main',
  template:   `<div class="prtm-wrapper">
                    <prtm-header-section></prtm-header-section>
                    <div class="prtm-main">
                        <prtm-sidebar-section></prtm-sidebar-section>
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    </div>
               </div>`
})
export class MainComponent  { }
```

I have already wasted hours on finding out the issue. Can you please tell me what am I  missing?

Comment: So you want to display a MainComponent inside a MainComponent? Why?

Comment: Sorry I made those changes later, just to check the code. I want to show UiElementsComponent.